# Why I am getting "Cannot redeclare class" error?

Tags: php

I have Apache running on port 81. My project folder is MyPhpProject. Inside it I have 2 folders: Domain and Testing.

In *Domain* folder I have 3 PHP files:

1. BaseDomain.php which contains an abstract class **BaseDomain**
2. Location.php which contains a concrete class **Location** inherited from BaseDomain
3. Employee.php which contains a concrete class **Employee** inherited from BaseDomain

Employee class has a reference of Location class.

This is the BaseDomain.php:

```
<?php
abstract class BaseDomain {

}
?>
```

This is the Location.php:

```
<?php
$returnRequire = require 'BaseDomain.php';

class Location extends BaseDomain {

    private $locationIdInt;         
    private $codeNameString;        
    private $descString;        

    public function setLocationId($locationId) {
        $this->locationIdInt = $locationId;
    }
    public function getLocationId() {
        return $this->locationIdInt;
    }

    public function setCodeName($codeName) {
        $this->codeNameString = $codeName;
    }
    public function getCodeName() {
        return $this->codeNameString;
    }

    public function setDesc($desc) {
        $this->descString = $desc;
    }
    public function getDesc() {
        return $this->descString;
    }
}
?>
```

This is Employee.php:

```
<?php
$returnRequire = require 'BaseDomain.php';

class Employee extends BaseDomain {

    private $employeeIdString;          
    private $locationObject;            

    public function setEmployeeId($employeeId) {
        $this->employeeIdString = $employeeId;
    }
    public function getEmployeeId() {
        return $this->employeeIdString;
    }

    public function setLocation($location) {
        $this->locationObject = $location;
    }
    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->locationObject;
    }
}
?>
```

Now in the *Testing* folder I created a Test_Employee.php and this is its code:

```
<?php
set_include_path('../Domain');

$getIncludePath = get_include_path();
echo "getIncludePath = " . $getIncludePath;
echo "<br>";

$returnRequire1 = require 'Location.php';
echo "returnRequire for Location.php = " . $returnRequire1;
echo "<br>";

$returnRequire2 = require 'Employee.php';
echo "returnRequire for Employee.php = " . $returnRequire2;
echo "<br>";
?>
```

When I try to run it `http://localhost:81/MyPhpProject/Testing/Test_Employee.php` I got a fatal error regarding cannot redeclare BaseDomain class. This is what I see in browser:

> getIncludePath = ../Domain
>
> returnRequire for Location.php = 1
>
> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class BaseDomain in C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Apache Software
>   Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MyPhpProject\Domain\BaseDomain.php on line
>   2

I have not created BaseDomain class more than once. So this error is bizarre. Can somebody please explain why I am getting error message? And how to fix it.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Use require_once instead of require.

Comment: Simple - you're using `require` instead of `require_once`. http://php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php

Comment: Indeed. In `Test_Employee.php`, you're defining it twice, once when you require `Location.php`, which requires `BaseDomain.php`, and once when you require `Employee.php`, which requires `BaseDomain.php`. This is exactly the kind of thing that require_once (which will skip the second require) is designed to fix up. Think of your PHP program as a single big file composed of all the included files put together; that's really how it works.

Comment: Even in Test_Employee.php when I change from require to require_once, I am still getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `$returnRequire1 = require 'Location.php';` loads Location.php, which in turns loads BaseDomain.php in the line `$returnRequire = require 'BaseDomain.php';`. Then, the line `$returnRequire2 = require 'Employee.php';` loads Employee.php, which loads (again) BaseDomain.php (the line `$returnRequire = require 'BaseDomain.php';`). The second load of BaseDomain.php causes php to try to redefine the BaseDomain class, which is no allowed.

The easiest way to solve this problem is to change your `require` calls to `require_once`. This will ensure that each file is loaded exactly once per run, which will prevent the error you are experiencing.

Comment: You mean use `require_once` in all the PHP files?

Comment: Yes. You should change every occurrence of `require` with `require_once` (there are some exceptions, but we wont discuss those here) throughout your php files.

Answer (score 0):

BaseDomain.php:

```
<?php
abstract class BaseDomain {

}
?>
```

Location.php

```
<?php
class Location extends BaseDomain {

    private $locationIdInt;         
    private $codeNameString;        
    private $descString;        

    public function setLocationId($locationId) {
        $this->locationIdInt = $locationId;
    }
    public function getLocationId() {
        return $this->locationIdInt;
    }

    public function setCodeName($codeName) {
        $this->codeNameString = $codeName;
    }
    public function getCodeName() {
        return $this->codeNameString;
    }

    public function setDesc($desc) {
        $this->descString = $desc;
    }
    public function getDesc() {
        return $this->descString;
    }
}
?>
```

Employee.php:

```
<?php

class Employee extends BaseDomain {

    private $employeeIdString;          
    private $locationObject;            

    public function setEmployeeId($employeeId) {
        $this->employeeIdString = $employeeId;
    }
    public function getEmployeeId() {
        return $this->employeeIdString;
    }

    public function setLocation($location) {
        $this->locationObject = $location;
    }
    public function getLocation() {
        return $this->locationObject;
    }
}
?>
```

Test_Employee.php

```
<?php
set_include_path(__DIR__.'/MyPhpProject/Domain');
require 'BaseDomain.php';

$getIncludePath = get_include_path();
echo "getIncludePath = " . $getIncludePath;
echo "<br>";

$returnRequire1 = require 'Location.php';
echo "returnRequire for Location.php = " . $returnRequire1;
echo "<br>";

$returnRequire2 = require 'Employee.php';
echo "returnRequire for Employee.php = " . $returnRequire2;
echo "<br>";
?>
```

Comment: So you have removed the require statement from Location.php and Employee.php. But each of these classes needs BaseDomain.php as they both inherit from BaseDomain. When I remove the require statement from Location.php and then try to access it `http://localhost:81/MyPhpProject/Domain/Location.php` I get this error message:

> Fatal error: Class 'BaseDomain' not found in C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache2.2\htdocs\MyPhpProject\Domain\Location.php on line 2

Comment: Edit set_include_path('../Domain'); to set_include_path(_ _DIR_ _'/MyPhpProject/Domain');

Comment: Problem is I cannot access Location.php and Employee.php now since you have removed this line `$returnRequire = require 'BaseDomain.php';` in these 2 files. Try `http://localhost:81/MyPhpProject/Domain/Location.php` or `http://localhost:81/MyPhpProject/Domain/Employee.php` and you will get a fatal error message: Class 'BaseDomain' not found.

Comment: BaseDomain.php, Location.php,Employee.php sava to MyPhpProject/Domain directory.  Please move Test_Employee.php to htdocs and http://localhost:81/Test_Employee.php cal url. Sory my English not god.

Comment: After your changes, the call to Test_Employee.php is working fine now . But call to Location.php is not working anymore. And call to Employee.php is also not working anymore.